# Regex matching double hyphenated string

Tags: regex

Given the following regex:

```
^((?:\d+\s)?\w+(?:\s\w+)?)
```

which is working well to extract the first (up to) 2 words (preceded by a number, if there is one), how can I adapt it to included words that are hyphenated?

I tried adding `\-` after the first `w+`, but that only found the first half of the hyphenated word and broke the original functionality.

Some examples of valid matches are:

- 1 Two
- 3 Four Five
- Six-Seven-Eight
- Nine Ten

They are components of an address field and therefore, I suppose, might have an apostrophe somewhere too, how could I also check for that?

Comment: I don't think you need to escape a `-` outside of `[ ]`.

Comment: Try \-* because if xou leave out this quantifier, you only match hyphenated words

Answer (score 2):

Use `[\s\-]` instead of `\s`

`[\s\-]` would either match a `space` or `-`..

So it should be

```
^((?:\d+[\s\-])?\w+(?:[\s\-]\w+)?)
```

The above regex wont work for your valid matches..you should use the regex given below

---

A better way to match multiple words seperated by `-` or space would be

```
^\w+([\s\-]\w+){0,2}$
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and clarification on using square brackets. The first example is almost what I'm looking for, except it only goes as far as Six-Seven- when using my example matches. The problem with your last example, is that it will match more than 3 words. I need to constrict the match to the examples provided. Excuse my lack of regex understanding, but could you elaborate on how to match the examples I gave and no more?

Comment: @MrG you can use `{0,2}` check out the edit in the last regex